# PlaySound plays default windows error sound

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to make a simple audio player in C++ using the Win32 API library.

How this program currently works, is you select a file via file explorer, which then the file's location is saved onto a list box. When you press the "play" button, it takes the file location from the list box, and parses it to a function that uses the parameter to play the desired file.

But for some reason, instead of playing the desired audio file. It plays the default windows error sound, even though that the file is found.

I tried this with a test sound file, that is in the projects structure. I know the program can find it, but still gives me the same issue.

If somebody could help me, that would be great. I'm more than happy to update this post with more code if you guys want me to.

**Window Procedure (In oshyClient.cpp)**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {

    switch (msg) {

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wp) {

                case MENU_EXIT:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    break;

                case MENU_ADDAUDIO:
                    queue.addNewAudioToQueue(hWnd);
                    break;

                case BUTTON_PLAY:
                    char text[100];
                    SendMessage(queue.hAudioQueue, LB_GETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)text);
                    audio.playAudio(text); // The audio issue is here.
                    break;

            }
            break;

        case WM_CREATE:

            menu.displayMenu(hWnd);
            queue.displayAudioQueue(hWnd);
            audio.displayAudioControls(hWnd);

            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);

    }

}
```

**oshyClientAudioPlayer.cpp**

```
#include "oshyClientAudioPlayer.h"
#include "oshyClient.h"
#include <iostream>

void AudioPlayer::displayAudioControls(HWND hWnd) {
    CreateWindow(L"Button", L"Play", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 5, 10, 35, 25, hWnd, (HMENU)BUTTON_PLAY, NULL, NULL);
}

void AudioPlayer::playAudio(const char* audioLocation) {
    PlaySound((LPCWSTR)audioLocation, 0, SND_FILENAME);
}
```

**oshyClientAudioQueue.cpp**

```
#include "oshyClientAudioQueue.h"
#include "oshyClient.h"

void AudioQueue::displayAudioQueue(HWND hWnd) {

    hAudioQueue = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"listbox", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | 0, 4, 92, 474, 250, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LISTBOX, 0, 0);

}

void AudioQueue::addNewAudioToQueue(HWND hWnd) {

    OPENFILENAMEA file;
    char fileName[100];

    ZeroMemory(&file, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    file.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    file.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    file.lpstrFile = fileName;
    file.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    file.nMaxFile = 100;
    file.lpstrFilter = "All Files\0*.*";
    file.nFilterIndex = 1;

    if (GetOpenFileNameA(&file)) {
        SendMessageA(hAudioQueue, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)file.lpstrFile);
    }

}
```

Comment: PlaySound is too basic for any audio player, at least use MCI

Comment: Remove the `(LPCWSTR)` cast, and then fix the problem the compiler is trying to warn you about.

Comment: `PlaySound()` is a very basic player, it can play only files types for which there is a system handler (driver) installed, typically `WAV` files, and can fit in memory. If you are trying to play types different from `WAV` the function will most probably fail. Anyway use `GetLastError()` to retrieve error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `PlaySound()`, you are type-casting a `char*` to a `wchar_t*`.  Don't do that. Use `PlaySoundA()` when passing in a `char*` string, eg:

```
void AudioPlayer::playAudio(const char* audioLocation) {
    PlaySoundA(audioLocation, 0, SND_FILENAME);
}
```

However, you are creating your ListBox as a Unicode window, so you should be using `wchar_t` strings instead of `char` strings, eg:

```
case BUTTON_PLAY:
    wchar_t text[MAX_PATH];
    SendMessageW(queue.hAudioQueue, LB_GETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)text);
    audio.playAudio(text);
    break;
```

```
void AudioPlayer::playAudio(const wchar_t* audioLocation) {
    PlaySoundW(audioLocation, 0, SND_FILENAME);
}
```

```
void AudioQueue::addNewAudioToQueue(HWND hWnd) {

    wchar_t fileName[MAX_PATH];
    fileName[0] = L'\0';

    OPENFILENAMEW file;
    ZeroMemory(&file, sizeof(file));
    file.lStructSize = sizeof(file);
    file.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    file.lpstrFile = fileName;
    file.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    file.lpstrFilter = L"All Files\0*.*\0";
    file.nFilterIndex = 1;
    file.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    if (GetOpenFileNameW(&file)) {
        SendMessageW(hAudioQueue, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! I really appreciate you helping me out. Yea the list box is unicode, so I've updated the post with the list box file. 

Unfortunately, the "wchar_t*" method still plays the default windows error sound.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You should be using Unicode for `GetOpenFileName()` as well

Comment: Hey, thanks once again for taking the time out of your day to help me, I really appreciate it. 

I did exactly what you've told me, but it still is giving me the same windows default error sound.

Comment: @nekloc it should be working just fine. Did you verify that `LB_GETTEXT` is returning the correct data as expected? What is the return value of `PlaySound()`? Have you tried the `SND_NODEFAULT` flag?